# Read files wih multithreads

Tags: java

I've got 2 files: is it possible to read the first file (some lines but not all lines)in processing, set pause to this reading, read the second file and set the reading to pause, then repeat the processing until the end of reading files ?

Perhaps is it possible with threads ? or just we a buffer ?

Comment: If you just want to alternate reading from two files, you don't need any threads or pausing. You can just create e.g. two BufferedReaders, and read however many lines you want from either

Comment: I would suggest using threads and locks for synchronisation

Comment: In reality I have the order to read file in an arrayList<Strring> = [ File1, File1, FIle2 ..., File1], so Buffers are better than threads to do it or not please ?

Comment: Well you should present those details (and many other details in your question if you want a specific answer). I would say to try it with the buffer see how it goes and then come back with a better question . Good luck

Comment: Ok, no problem i'm implementing solution using buffer and i come back with more questions :). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if it is possible? If so, yes it is, Java supports concurrency, just look up how it works. You could look into the readers writers problem. If you are asking how to implement that there are many examples specific to different needs, so you might need to be more specific and maybe include what you have tried so far.

If you would like to know what is the best way threads vs buffers it depends a lot on the situation, but as a minimum buffer should be enough

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have implemented bufferReader on my processing and it worked gratefully. 
My generall processing went from 11.5s to 0.65s to execution with 5000lines data to analyse.
So thank you :).
Im' trying to run with files of 1.000.000 lines.